# Set up smart mailbox to hold all messages to AND from a particular person

Tags: snow-leopard, mail.app, email

I want a smart mailbox that will display all the emails sent to me by a particular person as well as all the emails I've sent them.

I assumed that setting the rules to be

```
Contains messages that match ANY of the following;
From Is Equal To Person
Any Recipient Is Equal To Person
```

but all I get is messages from Person.

This doesn't do the trick so what am I missing? Shouldn't it return any emails sent from Person and any emails wherein Person is a recipient?

Comment: Did you check the box for `Include messages from Sent` and/or have you moved your sent messages out of the Sent folder into other folders?

Comment: Yes I have include sent messages set, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I haven't moved anything out of my sent folder.

Comment: Let's narrow down - remove the "From is equal to" line. Do you get anything then? What if you change `Any Recipient Is Equal To` to `Any Recipient Contains`? If that still doesn't work try changing `Any Recipient Contains` to `Entire Message Contains`.

Comment: Changing it to `From contains` and `Any Recipient Contains` worked. Thank you! I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both rules, change this portion:

```
Is Equal To
```

to this:

```
Contains
```

Utilizing `Is Equal To` requires an exact match against whatever you trying to match. Depending on how Mail is looking at a recipient's address, it may include brackets around it and/or include the person's name, in addition to the actual email address. These strings wouldn't match just the email address, obviously. Using `Contains` instead allows it to match the string you know should be there - the email address - no matter what Mail is actually matching against.